# Docker on Debian Failing to Bind to Port 80

Tags: debian, docker, lxc, apparmor, lxd

I am running Docker on Debian 11. I deploy an Nginx container and it fails to bind to port 80 even though port 80 is not in use by any other process. I even tried running Docker as root.

Here's the command: `docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx:alpine`

Here's the container logs:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2022/08/03 11:06:15 [emerg] 1#1: socket() 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] socket() 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

I suspect that **Apparmor is blocking the network access**. When I uninstall Apparmor everything works well. However, with Apparmor installed, only **privileged** Docker containers are able to connect to the internet.

Please let me know if you need any other information to help me debug this problem.

Comment: In case it matters, you should specify if you're using Debian's docker.io package or upstream's docker-ce package.

Comment: `permission denied` means that it's not allowed to open port 80 -- IE, it's not running as root (good, it shouldn't) and wasn't given privileges to open low ports.

Comment: I'm using Docker's repo to install Docker.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" in this case isn't so much that your system won't do what you're asking of it, it's that you're asking it to do something it really shouldn't.

Ports below 1024 are classed as *privileged* -- only root, or someone with the specific privilege, is allowed to open sockets on those ports.

Docker isn't running as root, or at least *shouldn't be*, so it can't open sockets on port 80. This is correct behavior.

I recommend setting Docker up to listen on a high port and localhost only, then using apache or nginx as a proxy.

Comment: The user that I'm running is part of the sudo group. I've tried other ports (greater than 1024), but none works. Switched to root and tried, same result. As I said in the post, only privileged containers were able to connect to the internet.

Comment: Being "part of the sudo group" only means that you can occasionally issue *specific* commands as root by prepending them with `sudo`. It does not automatically elevate your privileges on all situations, because that is explicitly not its job.